# Issues displaying 2 seperate Canvases at the same time in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have canvas A and canvas B.
Canvas A contains an Image and a grid with diffrent colour squares.
`numSelectCan` is a diffrent image.

Once i click on a square a event triggers that should set the visibilty state of `numSelectCan` to visible and then it should show up overlaping Canvas A.

That is not the case. I have tryed everything but i cant get `numSelectCan` to show up at all.
During development `numSelectCan` is displayed and works fine. At runtime numSelectCan is just gone. I tryed disabling A but still no success.

```
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,0,10,10">

        <Controls:RoundButton x:Name="btnCancel" PressedBrush="Orange" Foreground="White" BorderBrush="White" ImageSource="/Assets/Appgraphics/Buttons/cancel.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="btnCancel_Click"/>
        <Controls:RoundButton x:Name="btnQuestion" PressedBrush="Orange" Foreground="White" ImageSource="/Assets/Appgraphics/Buttons/questionmark.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,0,0" Click="btnQuestion_Click" BorderBrush="White"/>
        <Controls:RoundButton x:Name="btnConfirm" PressedBrush="Orange" Foreground="White" BorderBrush="White" ImageSource="/Assets/Appgraphics/Buttons/check.png" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="confirmSelection"/>
        <Canvas x:Name="picCanvas" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="582" Height="320">
            <Image x:Name="imgBackCC" Height="320" Width="582" Stretch="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Source="" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
        </Canvas>

        <Canvas x:Name="numSelectCan" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="155" Visibility="Visible" Width="530" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Image x:Name="numSelBackground" Source="/Assets/Appgraphics/UserInterface/numFieldBackground.png" Height="155" Width="530" Stretch="Fill"/>

            <Image x:Name="numFieldButton1" Source="/Assets/Appgraphics/UserInterface/numField0.png" Width="70" Height="70" Canvas.Left="5" Canvas.Top="5"/>
            <Image x:Name="numFieldButton2" Source="/Assets/Appgraphics/UserInterface/numField1.png" Width="70" Height="70" Canvas.Left="80" Canvas.Top="5"/>
            <Image x:Name="numFieldButton3" Source="/Assets/Appgraphics/UserInterface/numField2.png" Width="70" Height="70" Canvas.Left="155" Canvas.Top="5"/>
            <Image x:Name="numFieldButton4" Source="/Assets/Appgraphics/UserInterface/numField3.png" Width="70" Height="70" Canvas.Left="230" Canvas.Top="5"/>
            <Image x:Name="numFieldButton5" Source="/Assets/Appgraphics/UserInterface/numField4.png" Width="70" Height="70" Canvas.Left="305" Canvas.Top="5"/>
            <Image x:Name="numFieldButton6" Source="/Assets/Appgraphics/UserInterface/numField5.png" Width="70" Height="70" Canvas.Top="80" Canvas.Left="5"/>
            <Image x:Name="numFieldButton7" Source="/Assets/Appgraphics/UserInterface/numField6.png" Width="70" Height="70" Canvas.Left="80" Canvas.Top="80"/>
            <Image x:Name="numFieldButton8" Source="/Assets/Appgraphics/UserInterface/numField7.png" Width="70" Height="70" Canvas.Left="155" Canvas.Top="80"/>
            <Image x:Name="numFieldButton9" Source="/Assets/Appgraphics/UserInterface/numField8.png" Width="70" Height="70" Canvas.Left="230" Canvas.Top="80"/>
            <Image x:Name="numFieldButton10" Source="/Assets/Appgraphics/UserInterface/numField9.png" Width="70" Height="70" Canvas.Left="305" Canvas.Top="80"/>
            <Image x:Name="numFieldDelButton" Source="/Assets/appgraphics/UserInterface/numFieldDelete.png" Width="145" Height="145" Canvas.Top="5" Canvas.Left="380" />
        </Canvas>

    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

Not sure what is going wrong here, or if im missing a simple thing like setting the display order for the diffrent canvases

Any Ideas/Advice is appreciated.

*Update*
I added the entire content panel from my xaml.

heres the function that creates the grid for me when the page is initialized

```
public void createGrid()
    {
        //create the grid
        Grid backGrid = new Grid();
        backGrid.Width = 530;
        backGrid.Height = 285;
        backGrid.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        backGrid.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
        backGrid.ShowGridLines = false;
        backGrid.Margin = new Thickness(25, 15, 0, 0);

        //define columns
        for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++)
        {
            ColumnDefinition colDef = new ColumnDefinition();
            backGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDef);
        }

        //define rows
        for (int r = 0; r < 6; r++)
        {
            RowDefinition rowDef = new RowDefinition();
            backGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDef);
        }


        //colour counter
        int counter = 0;

        //create textboxes
        for (int r = 0; r < 6; r++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++)
            {
                //set the coulour of the canvases based on the counter
                if (counter == 4)
                {
                    counter = 0;
                }

                SolidColorBrush tempBrush = new SolidColorBrush();

                switch (counter)
                {
                    case 0:
                        tempBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        tempBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        tempBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        tempBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
                        break;
                }

                string canName = c.ToString() + r.ToString();
                string txtName = "text" + c.ToString() + r.ToString();
                string tempCanName = "canvas" + c.ToString() + r.ToString();

                //creating the canvas
                Canvas tempCanvas = new Canvas();
                tempCanvas.Name = tempCanName;
                tempCanvas.Background = tempBrush;
                tempCanvas.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
                tempCanvas.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
                tempCanvas.Margin = new Thickness(2);


                //creating the textblock
                TextBlock tempName = new TextBlock();
                tempName.Width = 32;
                tempName.Height = 32;
                tempName.Name = txtName;
                tempName.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
                tempName.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
                tempName.Margin = new Thickness(13, 0, 0, 0);
                tempName.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
                tempName.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
                tempName.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
                tempName.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                tempName.FontSize = 30;

                tempName.Tap += tempName_Tap;


                //adding the canvas to the grid
                Grid.SetRow(tempCanvas, r);
                Grid.SetColumn(tempCanvas, c);

                //adding all items into the canvas and into the grid
                tempCanvas.Children.Add(tempName);
                backGrid.Children.Add(tempCanvas);

                //increment counter
                counter++;
            }
        }

        //add the grid into the mainpage

        picCanvas.Children.Add(backGrid);

    }
```

All of this works. I get the grid with all the diffrent colour squares, but when I press textblock, I want my 2nd canvas to pop up and that does not happen. I added breakpoints through out and it goes through all of them, i just dont see the second canvas

heres the code for capturing the tap on the textblock

```
        //function that handels the event when a textblock is tapped
    private void tempName_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        //create a copy of the object that triggerd this event
        TextBlock tempBlock = sender as TextBlock;
        //create a string from the name of this textblock and then cut of the textpart from the name
        string tempName = tempBlock.Name;
        tempName = tempName.Substring(4);

        //move the canvas top or bottom based on which row the current selection is in
        string currentRow = tempName.Substring(1);
        if ((currentRow == "0") || (currentRow == "1") || (currentRow == "2"))
        {
            numSelectCan.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
        }
        else
        {
            numSelectCan.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
        }
        //show the number selector control
        numSelectCan.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

    }
```

I am still stuck on this. Cant get `numSelectCan` to show up...

Comment: Add more of your xaml showing your trigger to show the visibility condition getting fired off, and as long as they're both in a grid then B should show over A.

Comment: You need to post all your XAML because obviously something is afoot. For example if you have both of these items in a stack panel then the first canvas might push the second canvas off the screen. Please post the rest of your code

Comment: I have updated it with all the additional details. Currently still stuck on this

Comment: Even if i set the visibility to visible in the compiler during runtime i cant see canvas B. In the compiler before runtime it displays all nicely, the moment i start the app its gone.

Comment: I think it would be better if you put the whole of your project somewhere, it's hard to grasp into it as it is now.

Answer (score 0):

hello I have tried your code and what i found is that your question is little bit confusing so         i assume that you want your second canvas to be visible on tap on the textblock. but you have not register any event-handler on tap on textblock so no event fired  that's why first make your textblock visible and add a tap event handler on which you can set the visibility of second canvas. 
also tempName_Tap eventHandler is you color gridbox eventhandler not a textblock tap eventhandler so it never register you tap on text block.
Also in the beginning you write that you want your second canvas to be visible on tap on the grid box for that your code is working fine.

Comment: if you read the createGrid function you can see that the event handler is added to the visible textblock in each grid cell. On tap it registers the input but i cant get "numSelectCan" to show up ever. Even if the visibility is set to visible as standard. It shows in the compiler, and during runtime its gone

Comment: so you want that when you tap on color box the "numSelectCan" canvas should show up if it is right then your code is working. "numSelectCan" canvas is visible according to your condition of setcanvas_top or setcanvas_bottom . plzz it is not right just  explain your problem again briefly. I have check it on device. also i have change the backgrounds to blue and black to notice the canvas.

Comment: u tap the textblock. the 1 canvas visibility is set to visible and it should show, but it doesnt. the code looks all right and should work but the canvas just doesnt show during run time. its nowhere to be found

Comment: the problem is that i can see the canvas working and displaying properly in the compiler, but once i run it on the simulator it doesnt work

Comment: are you taking about this textblock {TextBlock x:Name="testShow" }  or the textblocks in the canvas of the grids..and i am checking on phone directly and it is working fine. are you doing it on windows 8 or wp8..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32489/discussion-between-tanuj-loop-and-wank-r)

Answer (score 0):

I took your xaml/code and tested it out with my own images.  Without the images (or entire project) to see how they are drawing on the canvas, I have to say there is a chance that you don't have the correct Z-Index for your 2 canvases.  They normally are layered one on top of the other not shifted off to one side.  You can set which Canvas is on top of the other by setting the `SetZIndex`.  Try calling:

```
    //show the number selector control
    numSelectCan.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    Canvas.SetZIndex(numSelectCan, 5);
```

and to hide it again:

```
    //Hide the number selector control
    numSelectCan.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    Canvas.SetZIndex(numSelectCan, -5);
```

Of course the Hidden and changing the ZIndex order might be a little redundant.  But I have had trouble with one of the canvases taking the events instead of the one that is displayed so I do both.